# Freeze a function called in an other one

Tags: r, function, reference, global

I was thinking R does not use pointers nor references. However, I have faced the issue of dynamic changes into a function. Here's a MWE to make my point clear:

```
> a = function(x) 2
> b = function(x) a(x)
> b(4)
[1] 2
> a = function(x) 3
> b(4)
[1] 3
```

while I was expecting changing `a` won't change `b`. For example, if I do:

```
> a = function(x) 2
> b  = a
> b(4)
[1] 2
> a = function(x) 3
> b(4)
[1] 2
```

I understand in the first case no copy of `a` is done; instead R looks for a function `a` into the GlobalEnvir each time I call `b` while in the second one it makes a copy, is that correct ? But if my function `a` is iteratively modified while I want `b` to use it as it was at the right moment where I defined `b`, what is the right way to do it. For now, I have thought using a copy of `a`:

```
> a = function(x) 2
> aa = a
> b = function(x) aa(x)
> b(4)
[1] 2
> a = function(x) 3
> b(4)
[1] 2
```

but this won't work if I update `a` more than once (because I'll also update `aa`).

thanks

Comment: I don't get your last sentence, are you redefining `b` too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a scope problem. You can force `b` to evaluate the `a` in a certain environment. For example  here a solution using `local`:

```
for(y in 1:5){
  b <- local({
    a = function(x) paste("old",x,y)
    function(x)  a(x)
  })
  a = function(x) paste("new",x,y)
  print(b(4))
}

[1] "old 4 1"
[1] "old 4 2"
[1] "old 4 3"
[1] "old 4 4"
[1] "old 4 5"
```

`local` will evaluate the expression within the local environment. It creates a new empty environment

Comment: thanks, but what if I can't define `a` straight away like that ? Indeed, it's the ouput of a code and I just can call it. R "should" understand that I want him to make a copy of that specific function at this moment.

Comment: @clemlaflemme in this case store the value at the point in time where you wish it in a variable with a meaningfull name, don't call it again in another function.

Comment: answer accepted but I've also posted an answer below to solve the issue mentionned above

Answer (score 0):

@agstudy answer is fine, but in case `a` is a black-box, and using its solution, the trick may be:

```
a = function(x) "old"
b = local({
    aa = a
    function(x) aa(x)
})
```

Then both `a` and `aa` can change while `b` will still be defined with original values:

```
a = function(x) "new"
b(1)
[1] "old"
aa = function(x) "aa has changed"
b(1)
[1] "old"
```

Comment: Indeed hence `aa` is local to `b` scope. You're not changing it in your second example but creating a  fresh new global `aa` entry.

Comment: I've just noticed it's even possible to keep the same name as it makes a copy of the global variable into a local variable: `b = local({
    a = a;
    function(x) a(x)
})`